i.MX8M Mini Core0/Core1 Software Reset Issue - Core Hangs
I'm working with the i.MX8M Mini processor and trying to perform a software reset of Core0 and Core1. I have implemented the following approach where I set the reset vector using the SRC General Purpose Register (GPR) and then trigger a core reset using the A53 register. However, after resetting Core0 (or Core1), the core enters a hang state and doesn't resume properly. Here’s a summary of what I did:     Set Core0 Reset Vector: I wrote the high and low parts of the reset vector to the SRC_GPR1 and SRC_GPR2 registers.
Trigger Core0 Reset:
I used the SRC_A53RCR0 register to trigger a software reset of Core0.
void trigger_core0_reset(void)
{  
    #define SRC_A53RCR0_ADDR 0x30390004   // Address of SRC_A53RCR0   

    #define CORE0_RESET (1 << 0)          // Bit 0 for Core0 software reset   
   
    volatile uint32_t *src_a53rcr0 = (uint32_t *)SRC_A53RCR0_ADDR;   

    *src_a53rcr0 |= CORE0_RESET;  // Trigger Core0 software reset
}

I called the functions with:
set_core0_reset_vector(0x7E1000);  // Example reset vector address 

trigger_core0_reset(); 

Issue: After resetting Core0, it appears to enter a hang state and does not recover. I also tried this approach for Core1 with the same result — the core hangs after the reset.

So, one question to answer is the 'soft reset' functionality.  There is a 'vtor' on some CPUs which specify the vector table.  Does the soft reset turn off the MMU? Did you have the MMU on beforehand?  Do you have access to a debugger?  What tools are you using?  Bare metal, Linux, Zephyr, something else?  There will be 'reset' value defined in some manual.  I expect it will be an ARM Cortex-A53 document and not NXP (yes, this makes life complex).  I would start by putting some small loop in the reset vector and see if it starts to execute.  Probably not 'hang', but uncontrolled execution?

I see SRC_GPR2 in Vybrid and imx6 references, so this is NXP IP.  Did you have a reference in the iMX8-m docs?  Ie, what chapter are you following.
